# In-App Purchase fails on iOS 8, saying user details are incorrect

Tags: ios, ios8, in-app-purchase, itunes-store

We have an app with In-App Purchases, which is working fine on iOS 7. But on iOS 8, when a user tries to purchase anything in the app, In-App Purchase fails with the error “The Apple ID you entered couldn't be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again”, even though the ID / password are (we believe) correct.

This happened on any iOS 8 device we tested on (with six different models of iPhones and iPod Touches), and happens on 8.0, 8.0.1, and 8.0.2. We tried this with many different Apple IDs, and it happens regardless of whether TouchID or password is used for authentication.

The purchases work fine in the live version on iOS 7 as well as in the Ad Hoc builds on iOS 8. Only the live version on iOS 8 has this problem. Restoring purchases in the live version also works fine on all devices.

Has anyone bumped into this, can think of what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you paste in the pieces of code you use for the IAP? I recently implemented IAP in my app too, and it works just fine both in iOS 8 and 7.

Comment: At which point in the IAP process do you get this error?

Comment: @adam10603 after we add a payment to the queue, so it would be after this:

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:[SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product]]

We know the product is valid because the app is fetching and displaying its info (e.g. price) correctly. The problem is I can't isolate the issue, because as I said the Ad Hoc (and development) builds work fine, even on iOS 8. The behaviour is *meant to be* identical between Sandbox and live server, which is not for some reason.

Comment: So you say that the IAP only works with the sandbox apple ID but not a real one?

Comment: on iOS 8 yes. On iOS 7 it works everywhere.

Comment: Maybe real apple IDs can only be used after your app is released. Apple says in the documentation that if the IAP succedes with a sandbox account then things will be fine.

Comment: Here i face one problem that, IAP works fine for the sandbox, but **it doesn't ask for the user detail nor showing any confirmation dialogue for in app purchase in the live app**.  @adam10603

Comment: Weird. I have the same problem, but in reverse. The IAP works fine in the sandbox on iOS6,7 and 8. But in the live version it only works on iOS8