# In-app purchase not asking for login

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, in-app-purchase

I have tested In-app purchase in the Sandbox. It is working perfect. Now my app is live and when I click on buy button it directly goes in the app-purchase. It is not asking for username/password or existing user. Also I've not even logged in from the device too.

```
-(void)requestForProductWithCompletionHandler
{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *_productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kProductIdentifier]];
        _productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [_productsRequest start];
    }
}

-(void)purchaseProduct:(SKProduct *)product
{
    SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    if (!hasAddObserver) {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        hasAddObserver = YES;
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

#pragma mark - PRODUCT REQUEST DELEGATE
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    if (response.products.count > 0) {
        SKProduct *_product = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"GOT THE PRODUCT");
//        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APPNAME message:@"Product Loaded" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        [self purchaseProduct:_product];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnReport setEnabled:YES];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APPNAME message:@"Invalid product" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    [btnReport setEnabled:YES];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APPNAME message:@"Unable to load product" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];

}
#pragma mark - TRANSACTION OBSERVER
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                [self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:NO];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                [self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:YES];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                // For debugging
                // NSLog(@"Unexpected transaction state %@", @(transaction.transactionState));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try a different device?

Comment: Yeas. i tried in 3 device..

Comment: what is app name? i will check and tell you the problem...

Comment: I have the same issue and I got the reply from : [Reference link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057906/in-app-purchase-fails-on-ios-8-saying-user-details-are-incorrect)

Comment: I am having the same issue at the moment. Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your transaction observer to the AppDelegate instead of in the view Controller? Apple's best practices describe how/why to do this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2387/_index.html